# Connect from Kubernetes Pod to nginx hosted on WSL2 vm

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am using the WSL2 based engine for Docker and I have enabled Kubernetes v1.19.3

I have several Kubernetes services and pods running and I want to connect to a website hosted on the WSL2 VM.  How can I determine the IP address for that VM that I can use to connect from a pod?

I ran `hostname -I` on the VM and got an IP address for the machine.

I created a service and an endpoint:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-viewer
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8280
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: test-viewer
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 172.17.159.34
    ports:
      - port: 8280
```

I tried to use curl from one of the pods and got the following error:

```
curl http://test-viewer.default.svc.cluster.local:8080/index.html --output somefile
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed connect to test-viewer.default.svc.cluster.local:8080; No route to host
```

I run the following command on the WSL machine without issue:
`curl http://172.17.159.34:8280/index.html --output somefile`

Comment: How do you normally access the website served by that VM? If is by using the IP you grabbed with hostname -I, can a cluster's node curl it?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on the service the specified port.
So either change the service port to `80` use the port 8080 on your curl

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-viewer
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8280
```

Comment: It didn't help to specify the port.  I updated the question to reflect that

Comment: can you ping this IP `172.17.159.34` from within the Pod?